# Не отображаются ticks на графике matplotlib, из за большого масштаба

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Отображаются метки только при масштабировании графика вручную. Как сделать так, чтобы метки автоматически распределялись по графику в зависимости от количества наблюдений? Требуется универсальный код для построения графика количества дат, чтобы метки отображались сразу без масштабирования и количество их было в некоторой пропорции от количества наблюдений.
Мой код:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df = pd.read_csv('My_df')

for x in df.columns:
    if 'datetime' in df[x].ftype:
    dates = df[x].map(lambda x: x.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
    dfdates = pd.DataFrame({x: dates, 'Count': [1 for x in range(0, len(dates))]})
    dfdates = dfdates.groupby(x)['Count'].size().reset_index()

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 7))
    ax.bar(dfdates.index, dfdates['Count'])
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator())
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b %d'))
    ax.set_title(x)
    ax.set_ylabel('Count')
    ax.set_xlabel('Date')
    plt.show()
```

Получается такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: непонятно что у вас делает цикл по столбцам DF... Можете выложить воспроизводимый пример данных?

Comment: Он перебирает все названия колонок в df и строит график распределений по этим колонкам в зависимости от типа данных, категориальные, количественные и даты. Выложил часть кода только, чтобы не путаться.
В этом коде что я выложил, цикл строит графики для столбцов, у которых тип 'datetime'

Answer (score 3):

Используйте свойство `plt.MaxNLocator`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

myscale = 10 # значение для maxlocator. либо постоянное,
             # либо вычисляйте его динамически так, чтобы вас устроил результат

ax = plt.axes()
ax.grid()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(myscale))
ax.bar(range(50), np.random.rand(50))
plt.show()
```

получим (для 50 значений):

[image: 50 значений]

а для 500 згначений

```
ax.bar(range(500), np.random.rand(500))
```

получим:

[image: 500 значений]

UPDATE 
Если задача сводится к отображению не всех тиков из набора, а, например, с каким-то шагом, то тогда еще проще:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ax = plt.axes()
ax.grid()
ax.bar(range(10), np.random.rand(10))
plt.xticks(range(10),['a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a'])
for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()[1::2]: #указываем начальный тик и шаг
# тиков, которые НЕ будут отображаться
    label.set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А уж с каким шагом отображать, в зависимости от объема данных, вы сами сможете вычислить.

Comment: Добавил часть вашего кода, метки с датами теперь видны без масштабирования, но все они перекрываются друг дружкой, словно отображение с шагом не работает. Что можно подправить? Практически ни как не знаком с библиотекой matplotlib.

Comment: Работает, но даже с шагом 2 идет перекрытие меток. Потому что довольно большое количество данных.

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in df.columns:
    if 'datetime' in df[x].ftype:
        dates = df[x].map(lambda x: x.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
        dfdates = pd.DataFrame({x: dates, 'Count': [1 for x in range(0, len(dates))]})
        dfdates = dfdates.groupby(x)['Count'].size().reset_index()
        lendfdates = len(dfdates)
        dfdates[x] = pd.to_datetime(dfdates[x])
        dfdates.sort_values(x, inplace=True)
        dfdates.reset_index(inplace=True)
        dfdates[x] = dfdates[x].map(lambda x: x.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 7))
        ax.plot(dfdates.index, dfdates['Count'])
        ax.set_title(x)
        ax.set_ylabel('Count')
        ax.set_xlabel('Date')
        plt.xticks(dfdates.index, dfdates[x])
        showticks = [x for x in range(0, lendfdates - 1, int(lendfdates / 9))]
        showticks.append(lendfdates - 1)
        [label[1].set_visible(False) for label in enumerate(ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()) if label[0] not in showticks]
        fig.autofmt_xdate()
        plt.show()
```

В общем, захардкорил такое (зато работает), showticks создает массив отображаемых меток динамически, в зависимости от размера данных. В итоге должно отображаться примерно 10 меток на графике. Спасибо @strawdog за наводку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]