# Временной ряд с большим количеством точек. Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Всем привет! Есть временной ряд в формате pandas Dataframe. При выводе графика подпись оси х выглядит ужасно. Второй день пытаюсь разобраться, но без результата.

Dataframe:

```
           date      time  price
0    2019-04-28  22:55:00  606.0
1    2019-04-28  23:00:00  606.0
2    2019-04-28  23:05:00  606.0
3    2019-04-28  23:10:00  608.0
4    2019-04-28  23:15:00  611.0
5    2019-04-28  23:20:00  609.0
6    2019-04-28  23:25:00  608.0
7    2019-04-28  23:30:00  608.0
8    2019-04-28  23:35:00  610.0
..          ...       ...    ...
191  2019-04-29  14:50:00  562.0
192  2019-04-29  14:55:00  562.0
193  2019-04-29  15:00:00  565.0
194  2019-04-29  15:05:00  565.0
195  2019-04-29  15:10:00  562.0
196  2019-04-29  15:15:00  560.0
197  2019-04-29  15:20:00  557.0
198  2019-04-29  15:25:00  556.0
199  2019-04-29  15:30:00  555.0

[200 rows x 3 columns]
```

Пробовал так:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': dates,
    'time': times,
    'price': prices
})
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df['time'], df['price'])
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

и так:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': dates,
    'time': times,
    'price': prices
})
plt.plot(df['time'], df['price'])
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('price')
plt.show()
```

Результат:

[image: График]
Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз вы используете Pandas, то попробуйте прямо из датафрейма нарисовать график. Я использовал 17 строк данных, которые вы предоставили. На графике видно, что Pandas сам уменьшил количество отметок.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [3]: df = pd.read_clipboard()

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
          date      time  price
0   2019-04-28  22:55:00  606.0
1   2019-04-28  23:00:00  606.0
2   2019-04-28  23:05:00  606.0
3   2019-04-28  23:10:00  608.0
4   2019-04-28  23:15:00  611.0
5   2019-04-28  23:20:00  609.0
6   2019-04-28  23:25:00  608.0
7   2019-04-28  23:30:00  608.0
8   2019-04-28  23:35:00  610.0
9   2019-04-29  14:50:00  562.0
10  2019-04-29  14:55:00  562.0
11  2019-04-29  15:00:00  565.0
12  2019-04-29  15:05:00  565.0
13  2019-04-29  15:10:00  562.0
14  2019-04-29  15:15:00  560.0
15  2019-04-29  15:20:00  557.0
16  2019-04-29  15:25:00  556.0
17  2019-04-29  15:30:00  555.0

In [5]: df.plot('time', 'price')
Out[5]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x7f1ed15ca6d8>

In [6]: plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно, вам нужно отображать не все подписи, чтобы график был читаемым.
Что-то подобное я уже советовал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/933021/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-ticks-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5-matplotlib-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0/933025#933025).

Принцип сводится к выборке:

```
for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()[1::2]: #указываем начальный тик и шаг
# тиков, которые НЕ будут отображаться
    label.set_visible(False)
```

Comment: Классный метод, взял на вооружение. Спасибо!